# Xcode compile errors from .pch? (iOS)

Tags: iphone, xcode

While making changes to an iPhone app I saved and compiled; got the errors below... undid everything and I am now stuck with these errors. I've tried cleaning the build, copying the files out of this folder, tried building on another machine. Nothing I can think of solves it, the change I made was to the .xib file; I removed the IBOutlet because I no longer needed the element.

Does anyone know how I can resolve these issues -> sorry for the long debug output but thought too much information would be better than too little.

```
Build Hunter of project Hunter with configuration Debug

ProcessPCH /var/folders/di/diNSUsegESCJmVpYf71u4U+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Hunter_Prefix-ewmgimmftydqkieofchvanjjzzvq/Hunter_Prefix.pch.pth Hunter_Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd "/Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New"
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -fdiagnostics-print-source-range-info -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk -fasm-blocks -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -fvisibility=hidden -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -iquote "/Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New/build/Hunter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Hunter.build/Hunter-generated-files.hmap" "-I/Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New/build/Hunter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Hunter.build/Hunter-own-target-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New/build/Hunter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Hunter.build/Hunter-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote "/Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New/build/Hunter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Hunter.build/Hunter-project-headers.hmap" "-F/Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-F/Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New" "-I/Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/include" "-I/Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New/build/Hunter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Hunter.build/DerivedSources/i386" "-I/Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New/build/Hunter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Hunter.build/DerivedSources" -c "/Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New/Hunter_Prefix.pch" -o /var/folders/di/diNSUsegESCJmVpYf71u4U+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Hunter_Prefix-ewmgimmftydqkieofchvanjjzzvq/Hunter_Prefix.pch.pth

In file included from /Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New/Hunter_Prefix.pch:7:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:11:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIActivityIndicatorView.h:8:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:10:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIEvent.h:9:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CoreGraphics.h:26:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGPDFContext.h:60:23: error: expected function body after function declarator
   CFDataRef metadata) CG_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_0);
                       ^
In file included from /Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New/Hunter_Prefix.pch:7:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:11:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIActivityIndicatorView.h:8:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:9:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIResponder.h:10:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIEvent.h:9:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CoreGraphics.h:8:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGBase.h:21:32: note: instantiated from:
 # define CG_AVAILABLE_STARTING __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING
                                ^
<scratch space>:82:1: note: instantiated from:
 __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__MAC_10_7
 ^
In file included from /Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New/Hunter_Prefix.pch:7:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:11:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIActivityIndicatorView.h:8:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:250:91: error: expected a type
 + (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0);
                                                                                           ^
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:256:86: error: expected a type
 + (void)transitionWithView:(UIView *)view duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0);
                                                                                      ^
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:258:114: error: expected a type
 + (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0); // toView added to fromView.superview, fromView removed from its superview
                                                                                                                  ^
In file included from /Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New/Hunter_Prefix.pch:7:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:13:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:187:31: error: unknown type name 'UIApplicationState'
 @property(nonatomic,readonly) UIApplicationState applicationState __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0);
                               ^
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:190:4: error: expected a type
 - (UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier)beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:(void(^)(void))handler  __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0);
    ^
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:191:28: error: expected a type
 - (void)endBackgroundTask:(UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier)identifier __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0);
                            ^
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:202:45: error: expected a type
 - (void)registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)types __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0);
                                             ^
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:206:4: error: expected a type
 - (UIRemoteNotificationType)enabledRemoteNotificationTypes __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0);
    ^
In file included from /Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New/Hunter_Prefix.pch:7:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:73:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UITextView.h:82:22: error: unknown type name 'UIDataDetectorTypes'
 @property(nonatomic) UIDataDetectorTypes dataDetectorTypes __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_3_0);
                      ^
In file included from /Users/stuartloxton/Documents/Hunter New/Hunter_Prefix.pch:7:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:79:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIWebView.h:54:22: error: unknown type name 'UIDataDetectorTypes'
 @property(nonatomic) UIDataDetectorTypes dataDetectorTypes __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_3_0);
                      ^
11 errors generated.
```

Comment: See this [post](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/66169?start=25&tstart=0) on the ADC forums for a workaround.

Answer (score 5):

I've just encountered the same problem with iOS 4 SDK. After I changed compiler from **LLVM compiler 1.5** to either **LLVM GCC 4.2** or **GCC 4.2**, everything returned OK.

Is it a Clang bug?

Comment: Changing compiler fixed for me too; can't really classify it as a Clang bug though so far. I've been unable to reproduce it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in 4.1, so if you haven't updated (yet) to 4.2, add this to your prefix file:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED 040100
#warning "Remove This in SDK 4.2, needed because of a bug in SDK 4.1"
#endif
```